# FOP XSL-FO Internal page anchor link URI problems

Tags: xslt, uri, anchor, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Morning folks!

So I am currently working on an FOP solution for a project, the end goal of which is basically to allow me to print onto a medium with the second iteration of the same information upside down, a feature which is not possible in Access 2007.

Everything is working swimmingly, and I can get the FOP to parse when I duplicate the code for the front side and use it for the back side.

However, when I try to use the  parameter, I am getting an error I simply don't understand from the FOP terminal, having spent the better part of 4-5 hours trying to get my head around it. Code and error to follow.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- WARNING - THIS TEMPLATE IS FOR Z FOLD CANON STOCK - DOUBLE SIDED -->
<!-- In order to covert CM to pixels, multiply the CM by 37.7952755905511, and round to two decimal places. It may be easier to use a spreadsheet to do this if you are editing multiple values -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <!-- EDIT THIS ROW TO CHANGE THE SIZE OF THE PAGE - AKA SET THIS TO THE SIZE OF THE MEDIUM YOU ARE PRINTING TO - CONVERTED TO PIXELS-->
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple" page-height="740.787px" page-width="317.480px">
                <!-- IGNORE EVERYTHING BETWEEN HERE-->
                    <fo:region-body/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <xsl:for-each select="//Person">
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                                <!--<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">-->
                                <!-- AND HERE-->
                                <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="370.4" height="634.96">
                                    <g class="mirrorpage">
                                    <rect style= "fill:none; stroke: black" width="370.394" height="317.480"/>
                                    <text x="37.8" y="122.83" style="text-anchor:start;" font-family="'ChevinLight'">
                                        <tspan font-size="20">
                                            Firstname
                                        </tspan>
                                        <tspan font-size="20">
                                            Lastname
                                        </tspan>                                        
                                    </text>
                                    <text style="text-anchor:start;" x="37.8" y="150" font-family="'ChevinLight'">
                                        <tspan font-size="20">
                                            Company Name
                                        </tspan>
                                    </text>
                                    <xsl:variable name="code" select="Code"/>
                                    <image xlink:href="LINK REDACTED"  x="37.8" y="190" height="50" width="50"/>    
                                    <image xlink:href="LINK REDACTED" x="250" y="200" height="100"width="100"/>  
                                    </g>                                    
                                    <use href= "#mirrorpage"  transform="translate (370.394 634.96) scale (-1 -1)"/>
                                    </svg>
                            </fo:instream-foreign-object>
                        </fo:block>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The error I am then receiving when I try to parse this is as follows:

[ERROR] svg graphic could not be built: file:/C:/Users/Events/Desktop/Angledtext/BadgePrinting/PDF/:-1
The URI '' specified on the element  is invalid.

From my (limited) understanding, there is an issue with the parsing of the "#" in the use line. I have tried to research URI properties but I have to be honest, I am completely lost.

Any help, or even a pointer to some relevant material I can read would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure which SVG version FOP and Batik support, I would try using `<use xlink:href="#mirrorpage" .../>`, but more importantly, you need an element with the `id="mirrorpage"` attribute so I think instead of `<g class="mirrorpage">` you want `<g id="mirrorpage">`. Also test whether the error is not related to the `image xlink:href` elements.

Comment: Aaah yeah, I did have it as g id mirrorpage, but was fiddling around with class to try and test whether the # was the issue. I have already eliminated the image xlinks as being the cuplrit, as this error only arose when I implemented the use element. Thanks for the help, i'll report back asap.

Comment: Yes, that was the solution, thank you very much for your help. One of those situations where i've been staring at it for so long I honestly didn't even notice the missing xlink phrase. Thank you very much!